# Application manifest schema

Tags: winapi, schema, manifest

Is there any documentation which describes all the valid elements for a Windows application manifest, which namespace they are in, and which Windows versions will use them? All the documentation I found so far describes only parts of the manifest, and I have seen different XML namespaces used for the same element.

What I have found so far:

- [Manifest Files Reference/Application Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to have full documentation of the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1` namespace plus the `compatibility`/`supportedOS` stuff (from the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1` namespace). It has a link to a schema file which does *not* have the `compatibility`/`supportedOS` stuff.
- [Step 6: Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) documents the `trustInfo`/`requestedExecutionLevel` stuff as being in the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2` namespace. However, I have seen other places saying it is in the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3` namespace.
- [SetProcessDPIAware Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documents an `application`/`windowsSettings`/`dpiAware` thing as using both the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3` namespace and a `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings` namespace.
- [Application Manifest XML Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd970597%28v=office.12%29.aspx) looks like a set of schema files for some of these namespaces, but it seems to contradict the other references (for instance, unless I am misreading the xsd, `dependency` is in the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2` namespace, while the first reference above implies it is in the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1` namespace).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such thing. In fact I'd bet that there are still some completely undocumented parts of the manifest. Indeed, for a long time the only documentation of the DPI aware part was in Raymond Chen's blog and book!

Comment: One such blog-documentation article is Chuck Walbourn's post dated 10 Sep 2013 at [MSDN Blogs > Games for Windows and the DirectX SDK > Manifest Madness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx)

Comment: Updated link https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/